# Concatenating in JQuery from 2 table columns

Tags: jquery

So I have pieced together the below and I'm not getting the expected outcome I am looking for

```
    /* Build SQL string */ 
$(".ConvertSQL").click(function () {

    $(".TableQuery").children("tbody").children("tr").each(function (i) {

        $("#SQLstring").val("")

        var $this = $(this);
        var my_td = $this.children("td");
        var first_col = my_td.eq(0);
        var second_col = my_td.eq(1);
        var query = "SELECT "
        var text = $("#SQLstring").val()

        query = query + "[" + first_col.html() + "].[" + second_col.html() + "],";
        first_col = ""
        second_col = ""


        $("#SQLstring").val(text + query) 

    }); 

    /* Remove some text from the start of the string thats not needed */
    $('#SQLstring').contains('SELECT [undefined].[undefined],').remove();

});
```

There are no errors I'm receiving as such.

The code loops through the first 2 columns in my table and build an SQL query

The current outcome is:

> SELECT [Test Table].[Test Field],

It should be basically concatenating eat row together to show something like:

> SELECT [Test Table].[Test Field], [Test Table].[Test Field],

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you define `query` within each iteration of the loop. You need to define it outside then add to it as the loop progresses.

Similarly you need to only update the `'#SQLstring` field after the loop completes. The setting of `#SQLstring` to empty can be removed along with the code to retrieve and concatenate it's value (which is redundant as the first thing the loop does is empty the value, so it's always empty). Try this:

```js
$(".ConvertSQL").click(function() {
  var query = "SELECT ";

  $(".TableQuery").children("tbody").children("tr").each(function(i) {
    var $td = $(this).children("td");
    query += "[" + $td.eq(0).html() + "].[" + $td.eq(1).html() + "],";
  });

  $("#SQLstring").val(query.slice(0, -1)); // slice is used to remove trailing comma
});
```

```css
input { 
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="TableQuery">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Foo</td>
      <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem</td>
      <td>Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button class="ConvertSQL">Convert SQL</button>
<input type="text" id="SQLstring" />
```

That being said a better approach would be to use `map()` to build an array from the values which you can then `join()` back together, like this:

```js
$(".ConvertSQL").click(function() {
  var query = $('.TableQuery > tbody > tr').map(function() {
    var $td = $(this).children('td');
    return `[${$td.eq(0).html()}].[${$td.eq(1).html()}]`;
  }).get().join(', ');
  
  $("#SQLstring").val(`SELECT ${query}`);
});
```

```css
input { 
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="TableQuery">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Foo</td>
      <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem</td>
      <td>Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button class="ConvertSQL">Convert SQL</button>
<input type="text" id="SQLstring" />
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I can also see you added the + to my =, Ive just looked this up and think I understand the syntax for that. Spent a while trying this. Doh!

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Note that I just edited the answer to include a better approach using `map()`

Comment: Thanks again for the help. Ive just moved it into the .map() method. Seems far better, ill need to do more work on constructing this myself as I had not heard of it before. 

One other question, my text outcome always starts with SELECT [undefined].[undefined]. I guess this is because its trying to read row 0 first?

Comment: That sounds like the likely cause. Without seeing the relevant HTML I can't really show you how to avoid it, though.

Answer (score 0):

**Your code would be like**

```
$(".ConvertSQL").click(function () {
    var sqlQuery = [];
    $(".TableQuery").children("tbody").children("tr").each(function (i) {

        $("#SQLstring").val("");
        var $this = $(this);
        var my_td = $this.children("td");
        var first_col = my_td.eq(0);
        var second_col = my_td.eq(1);

        var text = $("#SQLstring").val()

        var query = `SELECT [${first_col.html()}].[${second_col.html()}]`;
        if(first_col.html() != undefined && second_col.html() != undefined ){
            sqlQuery.push(query);
        }
    }); 

  $("#SQLstring").val(sqlQuery.join(',')); 
});
```

Comment: You can remove `var query = "SELECT "`